# ispconfig 550 Can't create directory: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, ispconfig

i just installed web panel ispconfig on my aws ec2 ubuntu 16.* LTS

now i am getting error when filezilla try to create new folder

```
550 Can't create directory: Permission denied
```

how can i fix this
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Permission denied
```

The issue, as the error hints. Is due to your permissions.
You need to set the correct (write and/or create, in this case) permissions for the user in FileZilla Server user configuration. Notice the Write/Create checkboxes below.

[image]

For further reference this guide is useful: [Basic configuration](http://www.uniformserver.com/ZeroXI_documentation/fz_basic_configuration.html)